# Jupyter Kernel dies/Spyder console stops while training custom NER model in Spacy 2.0.11

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, valueerror

I was trying to train a custom NER model in spacy. Initially I had installed the latest spacy version but was getting the following error during the training

> ValueError: [E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap.

After that I installed spacy version `spacy==2.0.11` and tried running my code. When I am having around 10 rows of data to train, the model is working fine and it's saving to my output directory. But when there is more data(5K rows) which is the original training data, my jupyter kernel dies or when I run in spyder, the console just exists!!

I understand that the deprecated version of `spacy` is not throwing the value error but still it's of no use as I am unable to train my model.

Sample data:

```
CarryBag    09038820815c.txt
Stopperneedle   0903882080f4.txt
Foilbags    09038820819.txt
```

I have around 700 files like this with data to be tagged and in each file multiple entities need tagging.
Code for reference:

```
import spacy
# import en_core_web_sm
import re
import csv
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
import plac
from pathlib import Path
import random

#Function to convert PhraseMatcher return value to string indexes 
def str_index_conversion(lbl, doc, matchitem):
    o_one = len(str(doc[0:matchitem[1]]))
    subdoc = doc[matchitem[1]:matchitem[2]]
    o_two = o_one + len(str(subdoc))
    return (o_one, o_two, lbl)

# nlp = spacy.load('en')
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
    nlp.add_pipe(ner)
else:
    ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')

ner.add_label('PRODUCT')     

DIR = 'D:/Docs/'
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)


list_str_index = []
to_train_ents = []
with open(r'D:\ner_dummy_pack.csv', newline='', encoding ='utf-8') as myFile:

    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            product = row[0].lower()
            #print('K---'+ product)
            filename = row[1]
            file = open(DIR+filename, "r", encoding ='utf-8')
            print(file)
            filecontents = file.read()
            for s in filecontents:
                filecontents = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', filecontents)
                filecontents = re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', filecontents, flags=re.MULTILINE)
                filecontents = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", filecontents)
                filecontents = re.sub(r"[-\"#/@;:<>?{}*`• ?+=~|$.!‘?“”?,_]", " ", filecontents)
                filecontents = re.sub(r'\d+', '', filecontents)#removing all numbers
                filecontents = re.sub(' +', ' ',filecontents)
                #filecontents = filecontents.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
                filecontents = ''.join([line.lower() for line in filecontents])
                if "," in product:
                    product_patterns = product.split(',')
                    product_patterns = [i.strip() for i in product_patterns]

                    for elem in product_patterns:
                        matcher.add('PRODUCT', None, nlp(elem)) 

                else:
                    matcher.add('PRODUCT', None, nlp(product))                
                print(filecontents)
                doc = nlp(filecontents)
                matches = matcher(doc)
                        #print(matches)
                list_str_index = [str_index_conversion('PRODUCT', doc, x) for x in matches]
                to_train_ents.append((filecontents, dict(entities=list_str_index)))
                break


        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

to_train_entsfinal=to_train_ents      




def main(model=None, output_dir=None, n_iter=100):
    # nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'spacy_pretrained_vectors'
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']

    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        for itn in range(10):
            losses = {}
            random.shuffle(to_train_entsfinal)
            for item in to_train_entsfinal:
                nlp.update([item[0]],
                           [item[1]],
                           sgd=optimizer,
                           drop=0.50,
                           losses=losses)
            print(losses)
            print("OUTTTTT")


    if output_dir is None:
        output_dir = "C:\\Users\\APRIL"


    noutput_dir = Path(output_dir)
    if not noutput_dir.exists():
        noutput_dir.mkdir()

    #nlp.meta['name'] = new_model_name
    nlp.to_disk(output_dir)


    random.shuffle(to_train_entsfinal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anyone help me solve this. Even when I removed conflicting entities in a sample of 10+ rows, example:

```
Blister       abc.txt
Blisterpack   abc.txt
Blisters      abc.txt
```

the same issue is happening and the model is not training

Suggested changes:

```
def main(model=None, output_dir=None, n_iter=100):
    top_memory_precentage_use = 75 # or what ever number you choose

    def handle_memory(ruler):
        if psutil.virtual_memory().percent < top_memory_precentage_use:
            dump_ruler_nonascii(ruler)
            ruler = nlp.begin_training() #or just init the nlp object again
        return ruler

    # This fitted for my use case
    def dump_ruler_nonascii(ruler):
        path = Path(os.path.join(self.data_path, 'config.jsonl'))
        pattern = ruler.patterns
        with open(path, "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for line in pattern:
                f.write(json.dumps(line, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")
        return ruler
    # nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'spacy_pretrained_vectors'
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']

    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        for itn in range(10):
            losses = {}
            random.shuffle(to_train_entsfinal)
            for item in to_train_entsfinal:
                nlp.update([item[0]],
                           [item[1]],
                           sgd=optimizer,
                           drop=0.50,
                           losses=losses)
            print(losses)
            print("OUTTTTT")


    if output_dir is None:
        output_dir = "C:\\Users\\APRIL"


    noutput_dir = Path(output_dir)
    if not noutput_dir.exists():
        noutput_dir.mkdir()

    #nlp.meta['name'] = new_model_name
    nlp.to_disk(output_dir)


    random.shuffle(to_train_entsfinal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell you **why** it is happening, but I can supply you 2 helper functions your training loop. that you can adjust to your use. In my case it was writing patterns and I checked the memory use every iteration.

```
#add the following imports
import psutil
import os


top_memory_precentage_use = 75 # or what ever number you choose

def handle_memory(ruler):
    if psutil.virtual_memory().percent < top_memory_precentage_use:
        dump_ruler_nonascii(ruler)
        ruler = nlp.begin_training() #or just init the nlp object again
    return ruler

# This fitted for my use case
def dump_ruler_nonascii(ruler):
    path = Path(os.path.join(self.data_path, 'config.jsonl'))
    pattern = ruler.patterns
    with open(path, "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in pattern:
            f.write(json.dumps(line, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi @Green thanks for the response. Can you please tell me in which part of my code shall I be using these functions

Comment: In mine I wrote it inside of the training loop

Comment: I have updated the changes under Suggested changes: in my question. Can you please let me know if it's the correct implementation. I am facing the same issue still after running the code with the changes

Comment: Where did you call the function? Seem like you just wrote the function and didn't call it.

Comment: I have made the code changes and updated it in the question section but the same issue persists. Can you please help me understand what your code is doing. And how this helped you resolve your issue

Comment: You didnt call the function, you didn't adapted my example code to your need andonly copy pasted it. You need to save the status of your object and load it again every time your RAM exploded. In my case it was just to dump it to a file.

Comment: I am unable to get the context of your code.. can you please tell me which object you are talking about?. I am using an updated version of spacy and getting an error like `[E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: '(92, 99, 'PRODUCT')' and '(92, 104, 'PRODUCT')'. A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap`. Were you facing something like this? What was the error that led you to this solution?

Comment: You have both these functions in your code? confused by the line `# This fitted for my use case`